# Fixed length SEQUENCE generation with Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have an Oracle SEQUENCE that I execute with the following stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE NEXT_NUMBER
(sequence_out OUT VARCHAR)
IS
sequence_num INTEGER;
i INTEGER;
iter INTEGER;
BEGIN
sequence_num := TEST_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL;
sequence_out := TO_CHAR(sequence_num);
iter := 6-LENGTH(TO_CHAR(sequence_num));
FOR i IN 1..iter
LOOP
sequence_out := '0' || sequence_out;
END LOOP;
END;
```

I need to get the next sequence number with the procedure and add zeroes at the beginning while the sequence is shorter than 6 digits long.

I have a for loop in the procedure that is supposed to concatenate leading zeroes to the string but I don't get the leading zeroes in the output.

Can anyone see why? Many thanks

Comment: See LPAD function or ever better use to_char (with formatting options) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions082.htm http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm. PS: the procedure is called `NEXT_NUMBER` and it returns string?

Comment: Why not use [`LPAD`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2017.htm) like this: `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NEXT_NUMBER( sequence_out OUT VARCHAR2 ) IS BEGIN sequence_out := LPAD( TO_CHAR( TEST_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL ), 6, '0' ); END;`

Comment: Thanks @ibre5041 but I figured it out. It it was is the format of the output. I printed a number instead of a char when I tested it. Many thanks.

Comment: LPAD is a good hint though, thanks!